# Using mysql and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

If connection to database is using mysqli like

```
$conn =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'db');
```

Can I still use the following code?

```
function get_book($book_id) {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT title FROM books WHERE book_id = '$book_id'"), 0, 'title');
}
```

Comment: test it? I think its easy!

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot mix using `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

And since [`mysql_*` functions are deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), the choice of which one to use is easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

We use mysqli in objective php. For "normal" procedurally php we use mysql. Read about it in php manual. You can't mix this prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

No. Mysqli is different from mysql, and you cannot use mysql functions with it. Also, the way I learned to connect to mysqli was not with mysqli_connect but like this:

```
$conn=new mysqli(/*credentials here*/)
```

see the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) on how to use mysqli

Answer (score -1):

It's not straightforward. You can still use the [procedural style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php), but you will have to add an "i" to function names.

i.e. change:

- `mysql_result` to `mysqli_result`
- `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query`

and so on.

```
<?php

function list_book() {

    $database_connection =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'db') or die('Could Not Connect' . mysql_error());
    $books = array();
    $books_query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM book");

    while ($books_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($books_query)) {
        $books[] = array(
            'book_id'    => $books_row['book_id'],
            'book_title' => $books_row['book_title']
        );
    }

    print_r($books);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean I can simply change mysql to mysqli and it will work in the same manner?

Comment: Correct. MySQLi is meant to work both on procedural and object-oriented style, but you will need to update your function names to include the i.

Comment: I used print_r to examine the content and it's empty.  Can I post the code?

Comment: I corrected the edit. You also need to add the "i" on mysqli_fetch_assoc()

Comment: Actually I also noticed that.  I corrected it and re-ran it but still it showed empty in the array.  i.e. the result of print_r is Array ( )

Comment: I inserted echo inside the while loop but doesn't seem code inside the loop was executed.

Comment: Make sure of the following: You are using mysqli_fetch_assoc();(example is wrong). Your query is not empty.  You are getting a valid connection

Comment: I did change it to mysqli_fetch_assoc() and I tried to insert echo and exit() at every step to see where it went wrong.  It was able to break before the while loop but not inside the loop.